# how to fix vlookup worksheet property error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following code which when run, returns error 1004 "Unable to get Vlookup Property of the WorksheetFunction Class" on the line ***"If strF = Qualified***". Please guide how to fix. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Geo()

Dim i As Long
Dim strB As String, strF As String, strResult As String

For i = 1 To 100

With ActiveSheet
strB = .Cells(i, 2).Value2
strF = .Cells(i, 6).Value2
End With

If strB = vbNullString Then
strResult = vbNullString

Else
If strF = "Qualified" Then
strResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B3"), Sheets("Pipeline Master").Range("B6:T3000"), 6, False)**

On Error Resume Next
strResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B3"), Sheets("2019-Wins&Losses").Range("A7:M5000"), 2, False)

On Error Resume Next
strResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B3"), Sheets("PipelineHistory").Range("C3:G15934"), 5, False)

On Error Resume Next

strResult = " "
On Error GoTo 0

End If
End If

ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value2 = strResult
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. If the VLOOKUP() fails (can't find a match), you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two `**` at the end of this code line `strResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B3"), Sheets("Pipeline Master").Range("B6:T3000"), 6, False)` ?
I tried it out and it worked fine.

edit: If it still doesn't work for you maybe try to use the `.formula` property instead.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pipeline Master").Range("B3")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""Qualified"",B6:T3000,6,FALSE)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```